# Send an email when the roles are changed

Tags: rules, users

I'm trying to send an email to users after their role has changed. So far, the rule is triggered every time the profile is saved (even without role change); I suspect that the data comparison is not handling the array correctly?!

Any help to improve the following rule or to achieve the same feature with a different condition will be very much appreciated.

```json
{ "rules_role_changed" : {
    "LABEL" : "Role changed",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "user_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "NOT data_is" : { "data" : [ "account:roles" ], "value" : [ "account-unchanged:roles" ] } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : [ "account:mail" ],
          "subject" : "Role change for [account:name-raw]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To detect 'any' change to the users roles, you can use the following PHP via the condition "Use PHP code"

```
return (count(array_diff_key($account->roles, $account_unchanged->roles)) + count(array_diff_key($account_unchanged->roles, $account->roles))) <> 0;
```

The other PHP answers will not necessarily fire when a user has been 'removed' from a role.

Answer (score -1):

You always need to check the state of both unchanged and changed account, something like this:

```
{ "rules_role_changed" : {
"LABEL" : "Role changed",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
"ON" : { "user_update" : [] },
"IF" : [
  { "NOT user_has_role" : {
      "account" : [ "account-unchanged" ],
      "roles" : { "value" : { "4" : "4" } }
    }
  },
  { "user_has_role" : { "account" : [ "account" ], "roles" : { "value" : { "4" : "4" } } } }
],
"DO" : [
  { "mail" : {
      "to" : "lorem",
      "subject" : "ipsum",
      "message" : "dolor",
      "language" : [ "" ]
    }
  }
]
}
}
```

What this does is it checks if the user had the role before it was saved, and if the role has been added on the update - this means that user did not have the role before but does have it now. 
Here is a screenshot of the config: [image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However we're not talking about the same conditions: what I want to do is to detect any role change; what you discuss (as far as I understand) is to detect whether a given role (here "test role") has been added to the profile. Would you know how to do the former?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to this old revision of an answer to a similar question, I figured out that you can achieve the expected behaviour by comparing the array in plain php:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/52790/2

Select condition "Use PhP code" with e.g. the following snippet:

```
// keys only must be compared since values are different (!). testing using empty() produces an error, hence the comparison of count() to 0:
return count(array_diff_key($account->roles, $account_unchanged->roles)) <> 0;
```