# How to send email confirmation mail to new user for custom role?

Tags: 7, users, emails

I have created a custom role i.e. `Passenger`. When user completes a custom form and submits the form, that particular user will be assigned `Passenger` role. Now my requirement is that when user completes the form, the user has to be notified with a confirmation mail for registration. How can I achieve that for other role (`Passenger`)?

In configuration of ***Account settings*** I can see only for administration role settings. How can do this for other role.

[image]

Comment: That administrator role button is for Drupal and it assigns permissions of newly installed modules to that role. It has nothing to do with mails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rule to send an email when role is changed](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/153346/rule-to-send-an-email-when-role-is-changed)

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, Its typo only. I am creating a custom form for passenger registration.